# How to update npm so it doesn't bootstrap on git push to heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

I am working on a Facebook Messenger bot that I am hosting on Heroku.

In my `package.json` I've specified my node version and NPM version as follows:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0",
    "npm": "5.7.1"
},
```

When I do a push to heroku using `git push heroku master`, I see the following:

```
remote:        Resolving node version 8.10.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.10.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 5.7.1 (replacing 5.6.0)...
remote:        npm 5.7.1 installed
```

What do I need to do to make sure that node version 8.10.0 and npm 5.7.1 are always installed so it doesn't need to do this with each push?  I assume this refers to the versions on the server rather than on my local machine?

Comment: This sounds like a heroku “issue”. Double check that this is default behaviour, and check their docs to see if you can turn it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll just leave this one as it is - it's not broken, so why fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
remote:        npm 5.7.1 installed
```

this doesn't mean Heroku is installing it every time, rather it is checking whether it needs to upgrade or not.

```
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.10.0...
```

Heroku creates a bundle for your application and this is done from your compressed file if there are no upgrades this will be done through your own bundle and if changes then will be upgraded through the server.
suggestion : if you are using Git then go heroku dashboard to **Deploy>Deployment method>and connect through Git**
this will auto-update your server files without using `git push heroku master` And speeds up the process